# How to view all the certificates that are loaded in to Chrome or any browsers or in to the OS?

Tags: tls, certificates, web-browser, certificate-authority, chrome

In Chrome, to view the certificate details of the site you are browsing, you can do a SHIFT+CTRL+I or navigate to: More Tools>> Developer Tools >> Security Tab.
But this will show you the details of the certificate of only the current domain you are visiting.

What I am interested is in browsing all the SSL Certificates that are held in my System (Windows or Mac).
Is it possible. If so, How do I access this information.

So, what I am looking for is
(1) Access or browse all the certificates installed in to chrome or
(2) Access or browse all the certificates installed in to any web browser
(3) Access or browse all the certificates installed in to OS (windows or linux).

Answer (score 4):

**Linux**: Exact method is distro dependent. There are answers at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97244/list-all-available-ssl-ca-certificates

**Windows** has no built-in viewer available, but there are third-party decoders such as CTLInfo ([website](http://www.trustprobe.com/fs1/apps.html)).

**Firefox**: Tools > Options > Advanced > Certificates > View Certificates > Authorities.

Some quick stats you may find interesting: As of today, based on a quick manual count, Windows trusts 362 root CAs. MacOS/iOS trusts 175 root CAs. Firefox trusts 160 root CAs. Android trusts 147 root CAs.

Comment: _"Windows has no built-in viewer available"_ - that's not technically true: Internet Explorer and Edge (incl. Chromium Edge) both use the Windows system certificate store which you can view with the Certificates tool: run `mmc.exe` , then load Certificates snap-ins for the Current User and Local Machine certificate stores, and browse away

Answer (score 2):

In Mac, you can navigate to 'Keychain Access' => 'System Roots' to view all the certificates.